# How to create DataSet in typescript like in .NET

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create variable that holds rows and columns with respective headers that how can create data set in .net. I tried with single and multi-dimensional array but i could not achieve my requirement in typescript. Can you please help me on this. Below is the sample i am trying to achieve.

**SAMPLE**

var dtEmployee which holds like below data:

**id    Name**  
1      Raam   
2      Jack   
3      Alex

Comment: Hi Team, Any help on this?

Comment: Hi team, have you had a chance looking into this?

Comment: Hi team.. Any update?

Comment: Hi team... Any help?